# Replace value in column dataframe python

Tags: python, loops, pandas, replace

Let's assume the dataframe below : df

```
Code         Type
 14 .        House
 15 .        Flat
 15          Flat
 15.         House
 16 .        Elevator
 17 .        Flat
```

I would like to do do something like that:

```
if df.code = 15, df.type.replace = flat
if df.code = 16, df.type
if.......
ect ect
```

The dataframe has 70k rows like that, with code from range 1 to 200

Comment: tried anything? there are lots of similar questions on SO if you search hard enough. Also your desired output is a description it doesn't show the complete picture

Comment: your question is not really complete, but take a look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html

Comment: I tried this but it did not work : df.loc[df[Code == 15].str.replace('house'), 'Type'] = 'flat'

Comment: df.Type.replace({'flat': 'house' }, inplace=True) works!

Comment: If it worked, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

df.Type.replace({'flat': 'house' }, inplace=True) works! –